# Monit - Adjusting host name

Tags: monit, system-monitoring

I have some systems which are provisioned via autoscaling groups and the host names are just the IP address of the system.

This is not very helpful in MMonit.

I'd like to do something like:

check system dev-kubernetes-minion-$HOST

But this errors out:

Nov 18 18:11:11 ip-172-20-0-5 monit[27043]: Starting daemon monitor: monit/etc/monitrc:12: syntax error '$HOST'

Is there a way to adjust the 'name' of the reporting system?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Post this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com); Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: @JimStewart -- totally would but the official MMonit webpage (https://mmonit.com/monit/) directs all users to use stackoverflow.

Comment: That's unfortunate.